# how to interact with a website through java program

Tags: java

i need to access this website(http://tamilnadu.schools9.com/anna-university-grade-system-exam-results200114.htm) to get my result through a java program please help me how to interact with the page in a java program.

Comment: Interact with in what way?

Comment: interacting means i like to give the registration number through the program and the result of the page has to be displayed in my java gui window

Answer (score 3):

You can use [HttpClient from Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html):

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://tamilnadu.schools9.com/anna-university-grade-system-exam-results200114.htm");
CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

try {
    System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
    HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(entity1.getContent());

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        // TODO: do something with the line
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
} finally {
    response1.close();
}
```